# How to remove a user from a user group?

Tags: users, user-groups

Ok this should be pretty simple I feel! But I can't find the documentation for it.

I can set assign a user to a user group within a plugin with:

```
craft()->userGroups->assignUserToGroups($userid, $groupid);
```

How do I do the reverse and remove a user from a user group?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assignUserToGroups` has `$groupIds` parameter (int / array) preset to `null`. From [the docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UserGroupsService#assignUserToGroups-detail):

> `assignUserToGroups($userId, $groupIds = null)`

So calling the function without that parameter set should do it:

```
craft()->userGroups->assignUserToGroups(1);
```

Comment: Ok thanks that does the job. Do you know if there is a way to remove the user from a specific group? Just forward thinking here. Cheers

Comment: Get all group IDs the user is assigned to and remove one group ID from that array, before passing it to `assignUserToGroups`.

Comment: That'll work cheers